# Setting a subset of orderers for RAFT application channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, raft

I am trying to create an application channel using `first-network` from `fabric-samples`.

1. I am creating the deployment to run 4 ordering nodes running in RAFT cluster. The following is the profile section used for creating Orderer Genesis Block in the `configtx.yaml` file.

   ```
   SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft
       <<: *ChannelDefaults
       Capabilities:
       <<: *ChannelCapabilities
       Orderer:
           <<: *OrdererDefaults
           OrdererType: etcdraft
           EtcdRaft:
               Consenters:
               - Host: orderer.example.com
                 Port: 7050
                 ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
                 ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
               - Host: orderer2.example.com
                 Port: 8050
                 ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
                 ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
               - Host: orderer3.example.com
                 Port: 9050
                 ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
                 ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
               - Host: orderer4.example.com
                 Port: 10050
                 ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
                 ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
           Addresses:
               - orderer.example.com:7050
               - orderer2.example.com:8050
               - orderer3.example.com:9050
               - orderer4.example.com:10050
           Organizations:
           - *OrdererOrg
           Capabilities:
               <<: *OrdererCapabilities
       Application:
           <<: *ApplicationDefaults
           Organizations:
           - <<: *OrdererOrg
       Consortiums:
           SampleConsortium:
               Organizations:
               - *Org1
               - *Org2
   ```
2. Now I want to create an application channel which will only have 3 ordering nodes (out of the given 4): `orderer, orderer2, orderer3`. So I set the profile section for application channel as follows (in the `configtx.yaml` file):

   ```
   TwoOrgsChannel:
       Consortium: SampleConsortium
       <<: *ChannelDefaults
       Capabilities:
           <<: *ChannelCapabilities
       Orderer:
           <<: *OrdererDefaults
           OrdererType: etcdraft
           EtcdRaft:
               Consenters:
               - Host: orderer.example.com
                 Port: 7050
                 ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
                 ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
               - Host: orderer2.example.com
                 Port: 8050
                 ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
                 ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
               - Host: orderer3.example.com
                 Port: 9050
                 ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
                 ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
           Addresses:
               - orderer.example.com:7050
               - orderer2.example.com:8050
               - orderer3.example.com:9050
           Organizations:
               - *OrdererOrg
           Capabilities:
               <<: *OrdererCapabilities
       Application:
           <<: *ApplicationDefaults
           Organizations:
               - *Org1
               - *Org2
           Capabilities:
               <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
   ```
3. I am using the default `byfn.sh` script to bring up the network.

But still when I try to fetch the application channel configuration block  from the `cli` container using `orderer4` envrionment, I am successfully able to do it and on decoding it to JSON file, I can see that all 4 orderers are part of the application channel's **consenters** section as well as every orderer's address is present in the **orderer addresses** section.

So, why is the application channel not starting with only first 3 orderers despite giving only those as the consenters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The channel creation command must have `-channelCreateTxBaseProfile` argument in it and the value for the argument would be the orderer genesis profile name (here `SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft`).

Also, the identity trying to execute the `peer channel create` command must satisfy the following ACL: `/Channel/Orderer/ConsensusType` (which is by default set to the following policy: `/Channel/Application/Admins`).

Comment: I'm trying the same setup for customising orderer for application channel but I'm getting `implicit policy evaluation failed` error, would you like to suggest, where and how to set the ACL policy?